# How do I switch the theme used on a Sitefinity based website?

Tags: sitefinity

We have a Sitefinity 3.2 site in production and the users want a whole new look and feel. Upgrading is not an option.

I have created new templates for them but they will need to go into the site and create all new pages using the new templates. This is a problem because they want the current site to remain unchanged until they are done - then they want to instantly switch over.

One problem that I see already is that pages will not show up in the menu control until they are published.

I am very new to Sitefinity. Is there a standard practice for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to re-create all of the pages to change the look and feel; simply change the template assigned.

[This video](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/video-tutorials/sitefinity-3-x/customizing-appearances-templates-and-themes.aspx) shows how to work with themes and templates.

I'd think that changing the theme of all the templates late at night should be "instantly" enough for most people. :)